# Angular - function inside .factory

Tags: angularjs, function, service

I'm trying to run a function inside .factory to get posts, but I get an undefined error on my controller.

```
.factory('Portfolio', function($http, $log) {
  //get jsonp
    this.getPosts = function($scope) {
        $http.jsonp("http://test.uxco.co/json-test.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
            .success(function(result) {
                $scope.posts = $scope.posts.concat(result);
                $scope.$broadcast("scroll.infiniteScrollComplete");
            });
    };
});


.controller('PortfolioCtrl', function($scope, Portfolio) {
    $scope.posts = [];
    Portfolio.getPosts($scope);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Fixed - having a doh moment! used .service instead

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is a `service` not a `factory`. so you either

- change it to be `.service` instead of `.factory`.
- or return the function inside an object like this

```
.factory('Portfolio', function($http, $log) {
    //get jsonp
    return {
        getPosts: function($scope) {
            $http.jsonp()
                .success(function(result) {
                    $scope.posts = $scope.posts.concat(result);
                    $scope.$broadcast("scroll.infiniteScrollComplete");
                });
        };
    }

});
```

[check the difference between service and factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angular-js-service-vs-provider-vs-factory)

Answer (score 0):

Use .factory code like this

```
.factory('Portfolio', function($http, $log) {
  //get jsonp
   return{
       getPosts: function($scope) {
        $http.jsonp("http://test.uxco.co/json-test.php?callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
        .success(function(result) {
            $scope.posts = $scope.posts.concat(result);
            $scope.$broadcast("scroll.infiniteScrollComplete");
        });
      };
    }
});
```